# PHP embedd XMLNode into a CDATA section

Tags: php, xml, cdata

I need to create this XML in PHP

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<processOrder>
    <key>X381tTD9w15HeEmgzbXbkfkUOW9srE</apiKey>
    <headerInfo>
        <![CDATA[<orderInfoHeader schemaVersion="1.1" softwareVersion="1.0.0" localCopyVersion="">
            <orderHeader>
                <uid>800</uid>
            </orderHeader>
        </orderInfoHeader>]]>
    </headerInfo>
</processOrder>
```

But I don't see a way to insert nodes into a CDATA, I tried with this but seems that only work with strings https://www.php.net/manual/domdocument.createcdatasection.php

Is it possible to insert nodes into a CDATA section on PHP with DOMDocument?

Comment: Have you thought about converting the nodes to a string?

Comment: XML does not have the concept of XML within CDATA, it's just regular text. You'll need to create a separate object for the inner XML.

Comment: ```$test= simplexml_import_dom($order_info_header)->asXML();
$cdata = $document->createCDATASection($test);```

This worked like a charm